# How not to output comments using the -C operation in mcpp

Tags: preprocessor, c-preprocessor

After using [mcpp](http://mcpp.sourceforge.net/) I have a comments code outputed to my working file. They looks like this:

```
#comments..
```

Does anyone know to to disable their output?

Answer (score 0):

-P operation instead of -C solved my problem.